# Nonsingular points go to nonsingular points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a regular map of quasi-projective varieties. If $x$ is a nonsingular point of $X$ does that imply $f(x)$ is a nonsingular point of $Y.$ Is the result true if $f$ were a regular isomorphism?

My attempt: If $f$ is a regular isomorphism the $df_x: \Theta_x\to \Theta_y$ is isomorphism and since $dim X= dim\Theta_x$ implies $dim Y= dim \Theta_y.$
Is my argument correct? is the result true if $f$ were just an regular map of quasi-projective varieties.

Comment: What about $f(x)=(x^2,x^3)$, $\mathbf A^1\to Z(X^2-Y^3)$?

Comment: So a regular map does not take nonsingular points to nonsingular.

Comment: is my argument fine for isomorphism? @tomasz

Comment: It seems correct, depending on what you mean by $\Theta_x$.